# Streaming large number of small objects with Java

Tags: java, serialization

A client and a server application needs to be implemented in `Java`. The scenario requires to read large number of small objects from database on the server side and send them to client.

- This is not about transferring large files rather it requires streaming large number of small objects to client.
- The number of objects needs to be sent from server to client in a single request could be one or one million (let's assume the number of clients is limited for the sake of discussion - ignore throttling).
- The total size of the objects in most cases will be too big to hold them in memory. A way to defer read and send operation on the server side until client requests the object is needed.

Based on my previous experience, WCF framework of .NET supports the scenario above with

- `transferMode` of `StreamedResponse`
- ability to return `IEnumerable` of objects
- with the help of `yield` defer serialization

Is there a Java framework that can stream objects as they requested while keeping the connection open with the client?

NOTE: This may sound like a very general question, but I am hoping to give specific details that would hopefully lead to a clear answer benefiting me and possible others.

Comment: So, for efficiency, instead of having a Java server request data that it would then serialize on behalf of some client ... why don't you simply have a REST server from which the client can request its objects directly?  Yes, the framework is called Java EE, except that connections are not left open with the client (which you really don't want to plan for anyway; such a strategy would be very non-scalable).

Answer (score 0):

A standard approach is to use a form of pagination and get the results in chunks which can be accommodated temporarily in memory. How to do that specific it depends, but a basic JDBC approach would be to first execute a statement to find out the number of records and then get them in chunks. For example, Oracle has a ROWNUM column that you use in order to manage the ranges of records to return. Other databases have some other options.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ObjectOutputStream / ObjectInputStream to do this.
The key to making this work would be to periodically call `reset()` on the output stream.  If you don't do that, the sending and receiving ends will build a massive map that contains references to all objects sent / received over the stream.

However, there may be issues with keeping a single request / response (or database cursor) open for a long time.  And resuming a stream that failed could be problematic.  So your solution should probably combine the above with some kind of pagination.

The other thing to note is that a scalable solution needs to avoid network latency from becoming the bottleneck.  It may be worth implementing a receiver thread that eagerly pulls objects from the stream and buffers them in a (bounded) queue.